# Evaluating $\sum_{i=1}^k \frac1d_i$

Tags: inequality, summation

Let $d_1, d_2,..., d_k$ be all factors oc a positive integer $n$ including 1 and n. Suppose $d_1+d_2+... +d_k=72$. The question is to evaluate $$\sum_{i=1}^k \frac1d_i$$

I found this question in Test of Maths at 10+2level. I tried applying inequality which made it ascertain that the summation is greater than $72/k$ but i  couldn't find it's value. Any ideas? Thanks. 
.

Comment: Take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330298/find-the-sum-of-reciprocals-of-divisors-given-the-sum-of-divisors

Answer (score 1):

Since $71$ is prime, $k=2$ is certainly a possibility, so ${72\over 71}$ seems a reasonable response to this question.