# Proving a relation between sum of reciprocal of divisors and $\sigma(n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, multiplicative-function

> Prove that $\sum_{d\mid n}\dfrac{1}{d}=\dfrac{\sigma(n)}{n}\ \forall\ n\geq 1, n\in \mathbb 
> Z$

My question and my approach is a lot similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330298/find-the-sum-of-reciprocals-of-divisors-given-the-sum-of-divisors) and a bit different from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157419/show-that-sum-nolimits-dn-frac1d-frac-sigma-nn-for-every-pos?rq=1) but just a bit short, I want to verify my approach. Here it goes:

***My Approach:***

Suppose $\sum_{d\mid n}\dfrac{1}{d}=\dfrac{1}{d_1}+\dfrac{1}{d_2}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{d_r}$

Thus $\sum_{d\mid n}\dfrac{1}{d}=\dfrac{\prod_{d\mid n,\space d\neq d_1}d+\prod_{d\mid n,\space d\neq d_2}d+\cdots+\prod_{d\mid n,\space d\neq d_r}d}{\prod_{d\mid n}d}$

Now $\prod_{d\mid n}d=n^{\tau(n)/2}$ and $\prod_{d\mid n,\space d\neq d_i}d=d_jn^{\tau(n)/2-1}$ where $d_id_j=n$

This means that the numerator equals to $(d_1+d_2+\ldots+d_r)n^{\tau(n)/2-1}$ or $\sigma(n)n^{\tau(n)/2-1}$

$\therefore \sum_{d\mid n}\dfrac{1}{d}=\dfrac{\sigma(n)n^{\tau(n)/2-1}}{n^{\tau(n)/2}}=\dfrac{\sigma(n)}{n}$

For the special case when $n$ is a perfect square, say $n=m^2$, then $n^{\tau(n)/2}$ can be written as $m^{\tau(n)}$ and $n^{\tau(n)/2-1}$ can be written as $m^{\tau(n)-2}$.

Please check my method. I am also trying to search for a more simple method than this. Thus any suggestions would be welcome.

***THANKS***

Comment: $$\sum_{d|n} \frac{1}{d^k}=\frac{\sigma_k(n)}{n^k}$$

Comment: @Raffaele, I'm sorry, but I couldn't understand what you meant by this and its relation to the given question. Can you please elaborate? Sorry if i didn't get this

Comment: It's a generalization of your property. $\sigma_k(n)$ is the sum of the $k$-th power of the divisors of $n$. If $n=15$ then $$1+\frac{1}{27}+\frac{1}{125}+\frac{1}{3375}=\frac{1+ 27+ 125+ 3375}{15^3}=\frac{392}{375}$$

Comment: @Raffaele, Oh, Alright I get it now. Thanks for sharing this generalization.